# Dynamic sum with JavaScript in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am trying dynamic sum with JavaScript in my Laravel application. It is working fine when there is one row. But if I make a for each loop, how can I get the sum for each row?

Here is my form:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="item1" type="number" class="prc form-control" name="item1[]">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="item2" type="number" class="prc form-control" name="item2[]">
    </div>
    <output id="result" class="form-group"></output>
@endforeach
```

My JavaScript code is

```
$('.form-group').on('input', '.prc', function(){
   let totalSum = 0;
    $('.form-group .prc').each(function(){
         const inputVal = $(this).val();
          if($.isNumeric(inputVal)){
               totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);
           }
      });
    $('#result').text(totalSum);
 });
```

[image]

I am getting the result in the first row only. How can I get values row by row?

Comment: what is your expected result ?? 8 is correct?

Comment: @A.ANoman I expect 4 in each row.

Comment: You may try dynamic `id` and `name` like add extra `foreach` key and add this key with `id` and `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have repeated `ids` so change them to `class` . Then , just add one outer div for per rows and use `.closest(".outer")` and `.find(".prc")` to loop through all inputs in that rows and then add total inside `result` using  `..find(".result").text(totalSum)`

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.form-group').on('input', '.prc', function() {
  let totalSum = 0;
  //get closest outer div
  var selector = $(this).closest(".outer")
  selector.find(".prc").each(function() {
    const inputVal = $(this).val();
    if ($.isNumeric(inputVal)) {
      totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);
    }
  });
  //find result add result there
  selector.find(".result").text(totalSum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--added outer div-->
<div class="outer">
  <div class="form-group">
    <!--use class-->
    <input type="number" class="prc  item1 form-control" name="item1[]">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" class="prc  item2 form-control" name="item2[]">
  </div>
  <output class="result" class="form-group"></output>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" class="prc  item1 form-control" name="item1[]">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" class="prc  item2 form-control" name="item2[]">
  </div>
  <output class="result" class="form-group"></output>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad i was able to help :)